The forgetful functor $\mathsf{Grp\to Set}$ reflects products
I am trying to show that the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Grp\to Set}$ reflects products.
I start by taking groups $G_i$'s and $P$, and group homomorphisms $p_i\colon P\to G_i$ such that these form a product in $\mathsf{Set}$. Now, the goal is to show that these also form a product in $\mathsf{Grp}$. From the universal property of products in $\mathsf{Set}$, I do know that there is a bijection from $f\colon P\to \prod_i G_i$ such that each $p_i = \pi_i f$. I would be done if I can show that $f$ is indeed a homomorphism. But I am at loss. Any hint?

If you compose f with the projection $\pi_i$, you get the original homomorphism $p_i$. You need to show that a function from a group to a product of groups is a homomorphism if and only if it is a homomorphism on each component.

Verify the conditions that would make $f$ a homomorphism using that $p_i = \pi_i f$.

@TCiur I see it now! Thanks. PS: If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Here is a more synthetic proof if you know that the forgetful functor has a left adjoint. A functor is conservative if it reflects isomorphisms. Your result follows from the following facts.

The forgetful functor from groups to sets is conservative: an isomorphism of groups is a bijective homomorphism.
A conservative functor reflects any limit which it preserves: if $F\colon X\to A$ is conservative, $x_\infty = \lim x_i$, $Fx_\infty \cong \lim Fx_i$, and $Fx \cong \lim Fx_i$, then $Fx \cong Fx_\infty$, and since $F$ is conservative $x \cong x_\infty$.
A right adjoint preserves all limits: if $F : X \rightleftarrows A : U$ is an adjunction, there is a sequence of isomorphisms natural in $x$
$$ X(x,U\lim a_i) \cong A(Fx,\lim a_i) \cong \lim A(Fx,a_i) \cong \lim A(x,Ua_i) \cong A(x,\lim Ua_i) \text. $$

Alternatively, the result follows even more abstractly from the fact that groups are a variety of algebras, that the forgetful functor on such a variety is monadic, and that monadic functors are conservative.

Whoa! that's a lot of concepts there! I will make sure to come back and devour each one of them!

I don't actually know much monad theory, so the information here is taken from nlab, but it is worth learning (and I will do so… someday). It is a large investment though; in the meantime the basic fact in 3 already cuts arrow chasing by orders of magnitude, and unlike monad theory is readily accessible. I suggest looking at Yoneda's lemma and adjunctions. Happy studies!

Since this is a category theory question, I will outline a category theory proof which could easily be translated to a set theory proof, if you wish.
Showing that $f$ is a homomorphism amounts to showing that the following diagram commutes
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P \times P @>{(f,f)}>> \Pi G_i \times \Pi G_i\\
@V{m}VV @V{m}VV \\
P @>{f}>> \Pi G_i
\end{CD}$$
Since we are mapping into a product, by using the universal property of products, it is enough to show that the following commutes for each $i$
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P \times P @>{(f,f)}>> \Pi G_i \times \Pi G_i\\
@V{m}VV @V{\pi_i \circ m}VV \\
P @>{\pi_i \circ f}>> G_i
\end{CD}$$
Now $\pi_i \circ f = p_i$ is a homomorphism which means the following commutes
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P \times P @>{(p_i,p_i)}>> G_i \times G_i\\
@V{m}VV @V{m}VV \\
P @>{\pi_i \circ f}>> G_i
\end{CD}$$
So it is enough to show that the following commutes
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P \times P @>{(f,f)}>> \Pi G_i \times \Pi G_i\\
@V{(p_i,p_i)}VV @V{\pi_i \circ m}VV \\
G_i \times G_i @>{m}>> G_i
\end{CD}$$
For this, note that $\Pi G_i \times \Pi G_i \cong \Pi (G_i \times G_i)$. Under this identification, $(f,f)$ becomes $\Pi_i(p_i,p_i)$. Then this last diagram commutes because that is how we have defined $\Pi_i(p_i,p_i)$, on components, using the universal property of products again.

How does $(f, f)$ become $\prod_i(p_i, p_i)$? Exactly how are you carrying out the identification? PS: I think that your original comment answered it much better.
